# Fredholm index independent of trivialization

Tags: functional-analysis, symplectic-geometry

Good evening!

My question revolves around the following: Assume we have a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ together with an $\omega$-compatible almost complex structure $J$, a smooth path $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R},M)$ and a Fréchet-differentiable operator $$\mathscr{F}: W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R},u^*TM)\longrightarrow L^p(\mathbb{R},u^*TM).$$

The goal ist to show that the derivative $D\mathscr{F}(0)$ is a Fredholm-operator. This can be done by taking a symplectic trivialization $\Theta:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^{2n}\longrightarrow u^*TM$, where $\Theta(s) : \mathbb{R}^{2n}\longrightarrow T_{u(s)}M$ is a symplectomorphism with respect to the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, and then working with
$$F = \Theta^{-1}\mathscr{F}\Theta : W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^{2n})\longrightarrow L^p(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^{2n})$$

Now the problem I have is with showing that different trivializations all yield the same Fredholm-index of $\mathscr{F}$. My idea was the following: Assume we have another symplectic trivialization $\tilde\Theta$, then $U(s):=(\Theta^{-1}\tilde\Theta)(s):\mathbb{R}^{2n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is a unitary matrix for every $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and we have:

$$\tilde F = \tilde\Theta^{-1}D\mathscr{F}(0)\tilde\Theta = \tilde\Theta^ {-1}\Theta\Theta^{-1}D\mathscr{F}(0)\Theta\Theta^{-1}\tilde\Theta = (\Theta^{-1}\tilde\Theta)^{-1}F(\Theta^{-1}\tilde\Theta) = U^{-1} FU$$
Due to the isometry of $U(s)$ for every $s$, this means $\ker \tilde F \cong \ker F $. Since both operators are Fredholm, $\operatorname{coker} F$ and $\operatorname{coker} \tilde F$ both are finite dimensional, and since $\phi\in\operatorname{Annihilator}(\tilde F)$ if and only if $\phi\circ U^{-1}\in\operatorname{Annihilator}( F)$, their cokernels are also isometric.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I think some thing is missing in your question. What about if $\mathscr{F}$ is a constant map. It derivative is 0 hence is not a Fredholm operator. Moreover what signify the term operator in Frechet differentiable *operator* . I think you mean "map" rather than (linear) operator. Yes?

Comment: After a possible revision the question seems very interesting

Comment: Is $\mathcal{F}$ meant to be the inclusion?